# Dynamic LINQ: Compare date between today and four weeks ago

Tags: c#, .net, sql, linq, datetime

```
BETWEEN CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AND DATEADD(WEEK, 4, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
```

This is how you do it in mssql. How can I do it using dynamic linq (or whatever it's called - like not C#, but strings).

I'll appreciate any help.

Comment: Viewed 18 times but nobody can answer?

Comment: What do you mean "dynamic linq (whatever it's called - like not C#, but strings"?

Comment: I assumed it means `"from a in b"` rather than `b.Where(a => ...)`

Comment: @Chris, your question is difficult to understand, it's not surprising that few people are willing to answer.  LINQ is a C# thing (I answered below with the assumption that you wanted a C# answer, but it's not in your tags and you said "like not C#" so it's not clear if you're using the wrong terminology or making an incorrect assumption.

Comment: @voo I did not know how to explain it, but harriyott got my idea.

Comment: @harriyott No, there's nothing dynamic about using query syntax over method syntax.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! When asking questions, there's no need to add tags to your title. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190 for the discussion of why they're not needed.

Comment: @Servy I wasn't suggesting there was. I was trying to clarify the intent of the question in response to voo.

Comment: @harriyott Have you not heard of dynamic LINQ.  It's a thing.  Rather than passing a delegate you pass a string to the operators such as `Where` that define the filter, with no type checking.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume this is C#.

if so, you are probably looking for something like this:

```
var theDate = {some date};
if (theDate <= DateTime.Today && theDate >= DateTime.Today.AddDays(-4 * 7))
{
    // stuff goes here
}
```

In terms of LINQ, it really depends on what you are trying to do, but this should give you the general idea:

```
var foos = from foo in SomeQueryable
    where foo.Date <= DateTime.Today
    && foo.Date >= DateTime.Today.AddDays(-4 * 7)
    select foo;
```

Comment: I'm sorry for my question being a bit hard to understand, but this was what I was looking for, so thx!

Answer (score 1):

```
var qryResult =   (from tbl in dbcontext.Yourtable
                      where  tbl.CheckDate >= DateTime.Today  
             && tbl.CheckDate <=  System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Calendar.AddWeeks(DateTime.Today, 4) )
            select tbl 
            ).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to know how to compare date in C# then:
Create an extension:

```
public static DateTime AddWeeks(this DateTime date, int weeks)
{
    return date.AddDays(7*weeks);
}
```

And so in Linq:

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
whatever.Where(d => now.AddWeeks(-4) < d && d < now)
```